# I am not getting any output in Log after writing code to download content from URL

Tags: java, android

I am not getting any output in Log after writing code to download content from URL.
I have been facing this problem from very long. My previous 2 apps are also not working because of this issue.
If you need screenshot of Log output you can ask as I am not eligible to add pictures with my questions.

> Java

```
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;

        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        try {
            task.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty").get();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = " ";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                int data = inputStreamReader.read();

                while (data != -1){

                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = inputStream.read();
                }

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                int numberOfItems = 20;

                if (jsonArray.length() < 20){
                    numberOfItems = jsonArray.length();
                }

                for (int i =0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
                    String articleID = jsonArray.getString(i);
                    url = new URL("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + articleID + ".json?print=pretty");
                    url = new URL(urls[0]);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                    data = inputStreamReader.read();

                    String articleInfo = "";

                    while (data != -1){

                        char current = (char) data;
                        articleInfo += current;
                        data = inputStream.read();
                    }
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(articleInfo);

                    if (!jsonObject.isNull("title") && !jsonObject.isNull("url")){

                        String articleTitle = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        String articleUrl = jsonObject.getString("url");
                        Log.i("Tile and URL", articleTitle + articleUrl);
                    }
                }

                Log.i("URL Content", result);
                return result;


            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> Log

```
2020-08-31 16:03:24.094 32480-32480/? I/mple.newsreade: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-08-31 16:03:24.159 32480-32480/? E/mple.newsreade: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-08-31 16:03:24.160 32480-32480/? W/mple.newsreade: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-08-31 16:03:24.697 32480-32505/com.example.newsreader D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2020-08-31 16:03:24.697 32480-32505/com.example.newsreader W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2020-08-31 16:03:24.684 32480-32480/com.example.newsreader W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:171): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=209 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c162,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.newsreader
2020-08-31 16:03:24.764 32480-32505/com.example.newsreader D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-08-31 16:03:24.783 32480-32505/com.example.newsreader D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-08-31 16:03:24.808 32480-32505/com.example.newsreader D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-08-31 16:03:25.331 32480-32480/com.example.newsreader W/mple.newsreade: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-08-31 16:03:25.331 32480-32480/com.example.newsreader W/mple.newsreade: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-08-31 16:03:25.719 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-08-31 16:03:27.186 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 2 of  [
2020-08-31 16:03:27.186 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.186 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.readArray(JSONTokener.java:424)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.186 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:107)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:94)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:110)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at com.example.newsreader.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:73)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at com.example.newsreader.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:47)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.187 32480-32516/com.example.newsreader W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.318 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd14dbf00, tid 32503
2020-08-31 16:03:27.337 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-08-31 16:03:27.341 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-08-31 16:03:27.343 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdcaa6f80: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2020-08-31 16:03:27.344 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdcaa6f80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe7c9ec30)
2020-08-31 16:03:27.371 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2020-08-31 16:03:27.374 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-08-31 16:03:27.374 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd14dd530, tid 32503
2020-08-31 16:03:27.378 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-08-31 16:03:27.378 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
2020-08-31 16:03:27.378 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff809000 size 0x2000
2020-08-31 16:03:27.396 32480-32503/com.example.newsreader D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdcaa6f80: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe7c9ec30)
```

Comment: There are several things to address in your code, but finding out exactly what fails is hard without your log. Does your app crash? If not, have you tried using breakpoints or log output to have a better understanding of where your code doesn't behave like you expect it to?

Comment: @Will I can't share screenshot of my log as I am not eligible to post images with questions on Stackoverflow

Comment: Copy-paste it as text

Comment: @Will Thanks, I have added log

Answer (score 0):

There are also several things to address in your code:

- You're fetching "https://..." so use `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection`
- `AsyncTask` has been deprecated (see [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)). There are better ways to run HTTPS calls. Use `Thread` for instance.
- You should probably catch different exceptions (`JSONException`, `IOException`, etc...) to make it easier to debug, and maybe show a different message to the end user based on the scenario (no internet connection, error in your JSON, etc...).
- Try testing your JSON with `if (jsonObject.has("title"))...` instead of (or in addition to) `!jsonObject.isNull("title")`
- You may want to close your `inputStream` and disconnect your `urlConnection` before using it again with a different endpoint.
- Use `StringBuilder` instead of `result += current`

Now, your error:

> org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 2 (line 73 of your file)

So your error happens at `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);`. You're trying to parse an invalid JSON. The JSON sent by the server is valid. The problem comes from how your read your input stream. If you output `result` before trying to parse it, you'll see that it's equal to `[`, which is obviously not a valid JSON.

Try this:

```
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
if (inputStream == null) return null;

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   data.append(line);
}

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data.toString());
...
```